# How to disable Lock screen when pressing Ctrl - Alt - Del in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, group-policy

I would like to disable the lock screen in Windows 10 when the user presses Ctrl - Alt - Delete. The default behaviour is that when this keyboard combination is pressed, a user is presented a lock-screen where he can selevt to log off, open task manager, and other stuff. I would like to disable this behaviour.

I already tried to set the Group Policy called "DO not display the lock screen", but this does not alter the behaviour when Ctrl - Alt - Delete is pressed. Is there any way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: CTRL-ALT-DEL is not the lock screen, but more of a system menu. Not sure this can be disabled by GPO, but you can definitely remove items from that list. What is the goal you want to achieve? CTRL-ALT-DEL can be used to change your password, which is a great way to instruct to users.

Comment: https://appuals.com/remove-options-from-the-ctrl-alt-del-screen-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Do this (requires administrator permissions) :

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Position to *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System >
  Ctrl+Alt+Del Options*
- Double-click Remove Lock Computer
- Click Enabled
- Click OK.

A reboot might be required.

Comment: This will remove the Lock computer from the CTRL-ALT-DEL screen, but Task manager and other settings are still there. This does not get rid of the CTRL-ALT-DEL service menu itself, which is what OP asks. See my comment under the question.

Comment: @LPChip: There are many ways to lock the computer: Start menu and CMD are some of them. Too many and some are impossible to block. That's why I think it's reasonable to answer just what was asked and not to extend it further.

Comment: As I read it, they call the CTRL-ALT-DEL screen a lock screen, but just don't know the terminology, and as I read it, they want to disable the CTRL-ALT-DEL screen entirely. My point being that this is technically not answering the question being asked if I'm right.

Comment: My reasoning is based on this text: `The default behaviour is that when this keyboard combination is pressed, a user is presented a lock-screen where he can selevt to log off, open task manager, and other stuff. I would like to disable this behaviour.`

Comment: @LPChip: I tried to block Ctrl+Alt+Del with AutoHotKey and it doesn't work. It seems unblockable.

Comment: Yeah, that is basically my point. OP seems to want something that is not possible, but I don't see that reflected in your answer.

Comment: @LPChip: We're discussing an issue that the poster can solve with a single comment.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. The reason I want this behaviour because I am running a Guest operating system running vmware-kvm (a vmware tool that runs a virtual machine) and I do not want the user to be able to escape the virtualized environment easily. At the moment, when vmware-kvm runs, a user can press Ctrl-Alt-Del and will get prompted the mentioned lockscreen from the host OS. This is the reasony why I want to disable this behaviour.

Comment: In that case @LPChip was right. But the answer then is negative - Ctrl-Alt-Del cannot be blocked. I believe that the keyboard itself causes an interrupt straight to Windows, and this cannot be blocked, even by a keyboard-intercepting program such as AutoHotKey.

Comment: I would make it so that the underlying layer is very restrictive anyway, so that even if the user gets there, there's nothing for them to gain. Might work if you set VMWare-KVM as shell. GPO can then disable items you want to disable